# Why is my device only 19Mb?

Tags: debian, mount, hard-drive

I have a 2To drive which is well recognized (on /dev/sda1), but when mounted (on /backup), does only hold 19Mb...

The other drives work very well, I also checked with fdisk and blkid, and the utilities tells me the drive is 2To as expected.

[image: A simple description of the problem]

*Is there an explanation to this ?*

Thank you

Comment: please run `echo p | sudo fdisk /dev/sda` and add the output to your question... `sda1` is a partition that contains a filesystem that is 96MB in size - it has 77MB used, and 19MB free. It is possible that your filesystem is only 96MB in size. by "2To" do you mean "2TB"?

Comment: please also use test blocks instead of images to post information